# Invalid syntax Twitter Python

Tags: python, twitter

I am using a premade script for Python to extract Twitter data using the API, when I run the script, I get an invalid syntax.

```
File "tweets.py", line 38
    print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this issue?

Here is the code before it:

```
#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

#keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

    #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
```

Comment: May I ask, what python version are you using?

Comment: You must be using a Python 2 script with a Python 3 interpreter. Either switch back to Python 2 or have the script translated into Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

As DYZ wrote in his comment, you are using Python 3 to run a Python 2 script.
You can easily update your script to make it compatible with Python 3. Just add brackets to print, because in Python 3 it is a function.
So change it from:

```
    print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
```

to:

```
    print("getting tweets before %s" % oldest)
```